# A Tk label that can be moved by dragging

Tags: ocaml, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to have a Tk label that can be moved in a window by dragging. Here's how I tried to get it:

1. Place a label by `place` using an absolute coordinate.
2. Bind the events `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease`, and monitor whether the mouse button is pressed. Also record the coordinate of the mouse pointer when the user start dragging.
3. Bind the event `Motion` and get the coordinate of the pointer.  Calculate the difference between the two coordinates, and add it to the coordinate of the label to get the new coordinate of the label.
4. Set the new coordinate of the label by calling `place` again.

Here's the code. It's written in OCaml, but I think it clear what I'm doing here.

```
let () =
  let t = openTk () in
  let l = Label.create ~text:"move me" t in
  place ~x:100 ~y:100 l;
  let d = ref false
  and xprev = ref 0 and yprev = ref 0 in
  bind ~events:[`ButtonPress] ~fields:[`MouseX; `MouseY]
    ~action:(fun ev -> d := true; xprev := ev.ev_MouseX; yprev := ev.ev_MouseY)
    l;
  bind ~events:[`ButtonRelease] ~action:(fun _ -> d := false) l;
  bind ~events:[`Motion] ~fields:[`MouseX; `MouseY]
    ~action: (fun ev ->
     if !d then
       let x = Winfo.x l and y = Winfo.y l in
       place ~x:(x + ev.ev_MouseX - !xprev) ~y:(y + ev.ev_MouseY - !yprev) l)
    l;
  mainLoop ()
```

It seems this works, but is this a correct way to do what I wanted to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using place and mouse bindings is the right way to do it.

Comment: Except that it should be `Motion` with the `B1` modifier; saves a lot of fussing around with boolean variables.